# React editablecontent div loses focus on typing/re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When typing in ContentEditable, every new character causes the element to blur and presumably re-render. When removing ContentEditable's parent element, Highlight, it stays focused, but unfortunately I need the syntax highlighting functionality. I tried adding a key to ContentEditable as suggested in a similar question, but that didn't work. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be a great help. Thank you!

Main component

```
var Stdin = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {html: ""};
  },
  handleChange: function(evt){
    console.log('evt: ', $.extend({}, evt));
    this.setState({html: evt.nativeEvent.target.textContent});
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },
  copyContent: function() {
    $("#fake-input").val($("#real-input").html());
    return true;
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id="stdin">
        <div className="arrow-right"></div>
        <form action="#" onSubmit={this.copyContent}>
          <input type="text" id="real-input"></input>
          <Highlight className='css'>
            <ContentEditable key="fake-input" id="fake-input" html={this.state.html} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </Highlight>
          <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      );
  }
});
```

Highlight component

```
var Highlight = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Highlight',

  getDefaultProps: function getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      innerHTML: false,
      className: ''
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
    this.highlightCode();
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function componentDidUpdate() {
    this.highlightCode();
  },
  highlightCode: function highlightCode() {
    var domNode = this.getDOMNode();
    var nodes = domNode.querySelectorAll('pre code');
    if (nodes.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i = i + 1) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(nodes[i]);
      }
    }
    return false;
  },
  render: function render() {
    if (this.props.innerHTML) {
      console.log("hey1");
      return React.createElement('div', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: this.props.children }, className: this.props.className || null });
    } else {
      console.log(this.props.children);
      return React.createElement(
        'pre',
        null,
        React.createElement(
          'code',
          { className: this.props.className, key: 'code-key' },
          this.props.children
        )
      );
    }
  }
});
```

ContentEditable component

```
var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
       return React.createElement('div', { onInput: this.emitChange, onBlur: this.emitChange, contentEditable: true, dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html: this.props.html}, id: this.props.id, className: this.props.className});
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        if ( this.props.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML ) {
           this.getDOMNode().innerHTML = this.props.html;
        }
    },

    emitChange: function(evt){
        var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
            evt.target = { value: html };
            this.props.onChange(evt);
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. My first solution was to remove all the `React.createX()` from the render method. Creating elements in React causes a rerender.

I've still got the problem, but maybe this solves yours.

Comment: I will try that! What do you recommend replacing `React.createX()` with?

Comment: @henrymb67 Try to make the element a seperate component in React. Refer to that component and pass its variables via props. Maybe this documentation helps a bit: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render and: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The pattern comes from the example for form inputs in react docs.

```
    var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {html: ""};
            },
            render: function(){
                var html = {__html: this.state.html};

                return React.createElement('div', { onInput: this.emitChange, onBlur: this.emitChange, contentEditable: true, dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {html}, id: this.props.id, className: this.props.className});
            },

            componentDidMount() {
                if (this.props.html) this.setState({html: this.props.html});
            }
            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                if (nextProps.html && (this.state.html != nextProps.html))
                    {this.setState({html: nextProps.html});}
            }

            emitChange: function(evt){
                    var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
                    if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.state.html) {
                        this.setState({html: html})
                        evt.target = { value: html };
                        this.props.onChange(evt);
                    }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue.

Comment: same it's likely that your parent is recreated so this would not fix the issue of blurring